# AmChart: How to zoom to a narrow range of data?

Tags: javascript, graph, amcharts

I would like to plot temperature with a zoomable x-y chart. A made a demo with AmChart at [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/ee1hare6/1/). However, I am not able to persuade AmChart to zoom to a narrow range of values between 1900 and 2016 AD. The problem is likely caused by presence of a lot of data values:

```
   ...
   {
    "x":-39855,
    "y":-4.81
   },
   {
    "x":-39782,
    "y":-5.08
   },
   {
    "x":-39710,
    "y":-4.53
   },
   ...
```

Do you have some idea how to load the graph with the zoom to values between 1900 and 2016 without trimming the data?

Answer (score 0):

With version 3.18 ([changelog](https://www.amcharts.com/blog/version-318/)) the [`maxZoomFactor`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmRectangularChart#maxZoomFactor) was introduced to rectangular charts (parent of xy chart). Its default value is 20 and prevents your chart from zooming further in.
 Setting it to a high value will fix your problem. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j3gergsL/).